# Angularjs Tutorial Step-0 bindings are not working?

Tags: angularjs

I just started looking at Angularjs today and I decided to try and learn it. I decided to start with the tutorial here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 and right away I'm experiencing an trouble. Right after the step of starting the server and going to localhost:8000/app the page that loaded looked like this "Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}". From my understanding it suppose to give me "Nothing here yet!" instead. I went further down the tutorial I and added `<p> 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }} </p>` and again the output was 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }} when it's suppose to be 1 + 2 = 3. I had not done anything to the sample workspace the tutorial provided it wasn't working from the start. Can somebody kindly shed some light on this problem?

Update: The code that I have is what is given to me from the tutorial and can be found here https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat but to show you some of the code

**index.html**

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML File</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */
```

**bower.json**

```
 {
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "angular": "1.2.x",
      "angular-mocks": "~1.2.x",
      "jquery": "1.10.2",
      "bootstrap": "~3.1.1"
  }
 }
```

Also when I look at the developer tools I see this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
bootstrap.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js"
angular.js
```

I know the error is that I can't find those files. Where do I get them? Do I have to download them separately?

Solved! Solution:

installed bower using `npm install -g bower` and then `bower install`

Comment: Did bower fetch the `angular.js` package? Have a look at the developer toolbar (F12) in your browser and have a look at the network tab and the console. Any errors there? Looks to me like angular wasn't loaded properly.

Comment: Please show us your code